# How to formulate exponential growth?

Tags: exponentiation

Here's my question:

> A rumour spreads exponentially through a college. 100 people have heard it by noon, 200 by 1pm. How many people have heard it
>
> a) by 3pm      b) 12.30pm     c)1.45pm

thanks in advance.

Comment: do you know the equation  for exponential growth?

Comment: In other words, it doubles every hour.  That should get you 3:00 PM easily.

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

(a) the number doubles every hour, i.e. multiplies by $2$

(b) the number multiplies by $\sqrt{2}$ every half-hour

(c) the number multiplies by $2^\frac14$ every quarter of an hour